# Change background color of some lines in vim/macvim?

Tags: vim, macvim

Is it possible to change the background color of some lines that I what to highlight? Thank you!

Comment: Do you have an example of what you want? I'm having a hard time understanding what you want

Answer (score 1):

The [wholelinecolor plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=5119) provides mappings to color the background of (`[count]` / selected) line(s), and even mappings to go to the next / previous colored block, or delete anything else.

It uses the *signs* feature to implement this; the nice thing about this is that it sticks to the current buffer (whereas `:match` is window-local and would need `:autocmd`s to properly stick), and that it covers the full line width, not just the amount of available text in that line.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the numbers of lines you want to highlight, you can use this commands
`:hi LineHl ctermbg=green
:match LineHl /\%15l\|\%23l/`